# cruzar 3 tablas en SQL SERVER y traer rango de fechas y horas

Tags: sql, datetime, join, diff, orderby

Tengo 3 tablas en SQL SERVER 2014. Tablas:

S20
AZUl
ROJO

con los mismos campos. Quiero cruzar S20 CON (AZUL - ROJO).

En la tabla S20 tengo un campo de fecha y hora y quiero saber si esta entre la tabla AZUL Y ROJO.

Los campos de la tabla S20 deben estar entre el rango de:

La fila 1 de la tabla AZUL y de la fila 1 de la tabla ROJO o de

La fila 2 de de tabla AZUL y de la fila 2 de la tabla ROJO y así sucesivamente.

Quiero que la consulta me devuelva la información solo de los campos de la Tabla S20 que estén entre cualquier rango entre las filas de la TABLA AZUL Y ROJO del mismo vehiculo.

algo como

WHERE fechahora.S20 BETWEEN fechahora.AZUL AND  fechahora.ROJO AND vehiculo.S20 = vehiculo.AZUL

el problema radica en que no se como decirle búsqueme entre en el rango de la primera fila de las dos tablas y devuélvame solo los datos que entre las dos.

el dato puede estar entre la fila1.AZUL Y fila1.ROJO o fila2.AZUL y fila2.ROJO.

La tabla S20 son los datos de un vehículo todo el día independiente este apagado o prendido.

La tabla AZUL son los datos de cuando el vehículo se prende

La tabla ROJO son los datos de cuando el vehículo se apaga

en resumen solo quiero consultar los datos mientras el vehículo estuvo prendido.

TABLA S20

2020-01-15T00:00:20.602000

2020-01-15T00:00:40.600000

2020-01-15T00:01:40.601000

2020-01-15T00:02:00.616000

2020-01-15T00:03:00.630000

2020-01-15T00:03:20.601000

TABLA AZUL

2020-01-15T00:00:20.601000

2020-01-15T00:01:02.275000

2020-01-15T00:02:10.616000

2020-01-15T00:03:15.630000

TABLA ROJO

2020-01-15T00:00:25.630000

2020-01-15T00:01:58.275000

2020-01-15T00:03:05.630000

2020-01-15T00:03:18.630000

COMO RESULTADO SOLO DEBERIA TRAERME LOS SIGUIENTES DATOS

2020-01-15T00:00:20.602000

2020-01-15T00:01:40.601000

2020-01-15T00:03:00.630000

La tabla S20 son los datos de un vehículo

la tabla AZUL son los datos de cuando el vehículo se prende

la tabla ROJO son los datos de cuando el vehículo se apaga

en resumen solo quiero consultar los datos mientras el vehículo estuvo prendido.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Supongo que esa desnormalización de las tablas vendrá por algo que no es importante para la pregunta, pero tengo que remarcar que no es un buen modelo. Pensar en intentar normalizar esa información sería importante.

Entrando en materia.

```
Create table dbo.[S20]  (vehiculo varchar(6),fechahora datetime2)
Create table dbo.[ROJO] (vehiculo varchar(6),fechahora datetime2)
Create table dbo.[AZUL] (vehiculo varchar(6),fechahora datetime2)
go
Insert into dbo.[S20] (vehiculo,fechahora)
values
('AAA001','2020-01-15T00:00:20.602000'),
('AAA001','2020-01-15T00:00:40.600000'),
('AAA001','2020-01-15T00:01:40.601000'),
('AAA001','2020-01-15T00:02:00.616000'),
('AAA001','2020-01-15T00:03:00.630000'),
('AAA001','2020-01-15T00:03:20.601000');
Insert into dbo.rojo (vehiculo,fechahora)
values
('AAA001','2020-01-15T00:00:25.630000'),
('AAA001','2020-01-15T00:01:58.275000'),
('AAA001','2020-01-15T00:03:05.630000'),
('AAA001','2020-01-15T00:03:18.630000');
Insert into dbo.azul (vehiculo,fechahora)
values
('AAA001','2020-01-15T00:00:20.602000'),
('AAA001','2020-01-15T00:01:40.601000'),
('AAA001','2020-01-15T00:03:00.630000');
go
```

Una solución posible, es utilizar el operador UNION para juntar s20, rojo y azul, y luego ordenar los resultados con row_number para determinar el orden y extraer los resultados que nos interesan, utilizando lag para saber si el registro anterior fue un encendido.

```
With c
     As (Select 1 As grp
              , vehiculo
              , fechahora
                From azul
         Union All
         Select 0 As grp
              , vehiculo
              , fechahora
                From rojo
         Union All
         Select 2 As grp
              , vehiculo
              , fechahora
                From s20),
     c2
     As (Select *
              , lag(grp) Over(Partition By vehiculo
                Order By fechahora
                       , grp) As lagGrp
                From c)
     Select v.vehiculo
          , v.fechahora
            From c2 As v
            Where grp = 2 And lagGrp = 1;
```

[image: Resultado]

Por partes:

En el conjunto "c", usamos las tres tablas, y las unimos, anexando una columna que nos identifica si es un encendido un apagado, o el dato que queremos extraer.

En el conjunto "c2" obtenemos el valor del registro anterior para esa columna de grupo que está ordenada por vehículo y fechahora es un encendido=1.

Y la salida final obtenemos los registros que sean de tipo 2 = [s20] y que su previo sea un encendido.

[Tablas de expresión común correlativas (cte)](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2018/12/18/with-cte-tablas-de-expresion-comun-2-correlativos/)

[Lag](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2018/09/11/lag-y-lead-siguiente-y-anterior/)

[Row Number. Numerar Filas](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2019/11/11/row-number-numerar-filas/)